# Adding "Closest location" search to a Django application

Tags: django, django-models, geometry

I have a Django application with a model that includes address fields. I want to implement a "closest location" search. Specifically, I want the ability to find the model objects closest to a zip code.

I know this is a broad question but I would **really** like to know where should I start.

I looked at GeoDjango, but after looking at [the tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/), it frankly feels a bit over my head. Perhaps there's an app that accomplishes something similar whose source I'd be able to look at.

Tips, potential obstacles and any helpful pointers would be **greatly** appreciated.